# Octave: Precise value in Decimal or Continuous Fraction for 729 / 4^3

Tags: octave

I get the approximation:

```
>> 729 / 4^3 
11.391
```

Is there some function to get more precise approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
octave:1> 729/4^3
ans =  11.391
octave:2> format long
octave:3> 729/4^3
ans =  11.3906250000000
octave:4>
```

---

Have you tried the "[format long](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Terminal-Output.html)" command?

I'm installing octave right now. I used to use it and Matlab while I was in college.

Comment: So it is not possible to specify the accuracy, eg to 128 decimals?